# QT Creator not generating executable files

Tags: qt

While creating and generating project on QT Creator on release mode, it is creating .o (object) files instead .exe files. Is there a particular configuration I am missing that I must do so I get the executable file instead?

I am new to the software and most of the instructions I find online on how to generate exe files seem to not have this issue.

Greatly appreciate in advance.

Comment: Qt Creator doesn't create object files or executable; it's an IDE only. Check whatever build toolchain you have set (Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits tab) is set correctly. Additionally, if you downloaded Qt binaries, make sure you downloaded the binaries that match the same build tools you have installed.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows Read this please...

Comment: So you built Qt from source on your system? Which did you use, Mingw or Visual Studio? Do other projects build fine in release mode outside of Qt Creator on the same system?

Comment: How dumb of my part it did created the exe file it is simply accompanied by a bunch of object files. Well I guess there was no issue after all. Thanks anyways. You helped by pushing me an extra mile to keep debugging.